# Don't know anything about Ubuntu, help me install a driver

Tags: networking, drivers

I have a [wifi adapter](https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/TL-WN725N.html) that doesn't work on ubuntu unless I install a driver. I don't have any experience with Ubuntu or the command line so please help. On the website for this product, they have a [driver for linux](https://static.tp-link.com/TL-WN725N_V2_150911_1480321613225x.zip) which includes a tutorial on how to install the driver. I can't understand it so can somebody please show me a step-by-step noob way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

More often than not, you'll find that devices "just work" on Ubuntu without the need to manually install any additional drivers. This is a concept that can be quite difficult for Windows users to get their head around.

The best thing to do is plug in an ethernet cable (temporarily) and do all your updates:

sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade

... then reboot and see if your wifi adapter works. If not, then you can think about installing that 3rd party driver, but chances are it won't be necessary.

Comment: the wifi adapter doesn't work on ubuntu without installing any drivers. I don't have an ethernet cable and I've been asking around if anyone has one, but if I could just install the driver that would be cool.

Comment: I'm guessing that you installed Ubuntu from a DVD or USB stick then? Without running the updates yet, because you have no internet connection? If this is the case then your best course of action is to find an ethernet cable and run your updates before you try to do anything else. This in itself may solve your wifi problem, as I've described.

Comment: yep i installed ubuntu from a usb drive. is there a problem with installing the driver without an ethernet cable? are there some other necessary things for ubuntu that will be downloaded as well? for now i'll look for an ethernet cable i guess.

Comment: update: i had ubuntu 16.04, now i've updated to 18.04. in the setup for 18.04, they asked me if i wanted to connect to the internet to install additional programs and for some reason the wifi adapter was working correctly. i am writing this comment on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: As I told you, devices "just work" with Ubuntu, all you have to do is update it. Please mark my answer as accepted if it helped you.